# Sending props from different routes to the same component using Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, components

I'm building a menu app using Vue JS. I was told that only have to use 1 component if the styling stays the same. So that means i have to use dynamic data. each menu/submenu has 3 to 4 menu links. I was looking for a solution to send variables with data to a component and came up with 'props'. But i couldn't find a way to send props from different routes to the same component and check which route you're on to know which props to load into the html.

I already tried to load props into a template, and that works fine. But sending and replacing prop values in the same part of html is something i haven't figured out yet.

```js
 { path: '/list', component: List, props: { url: 'www.google.com' } }
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welkom</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <router-link to='/weed'>Wiet</router-link>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <router-link to='/stuff'>Stuff</router-link>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <router-link to='/joint'>Joint</router-link>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <router-link to='/edibles'>Edibles</router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

the `<router-link>` should dynamic depending on which route you are, so it can load in different menu items.

I want a menu that loads in different route links depending on which route you are.

Comment: You may need `Vuex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use params from your route as props in your component and use a watcher to react to route changes. Either have a state system (vuex) with which you can access specific data regarding the params or just plainly use the params.

Use: `router.push({ path: '/user/${userId}' })`

then

```
watch: {
  $route(to, from) {
    // react somehow
  }
}
```

and/or

```
template: '<div>User {{ $route.params.id }}</div>'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use Programmatic Navigation and query params like

```
router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' } })
```

so for your application use

```
<div class="col-md-6"
     @click="$router.push({ path: '/edibles',
             query: { url: 'www.google.com', other: 'etc' }})"
 >Edibles</div>
```

you can access these query params in the navigated component using `$route.params.url` in a template and `this.$route.params.url` in functions and computed and all other properties of vue component instance.

also check https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html for details

**Edit as per comment**

I think you should still use Programmatic Navigation with

```
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId } })
```

the params provided can be used as props to the component as shown below

```
    const User = {   
    props: ['id'],   
    template: '<div>User {{ id }}</div>' 
} 
const router = new VueRouter({   
    routes: [     
        { path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: true }      
    ] 
})
```

just remember to set `props: true` in routes definition!

Comment: I'm not sure, but i don't think that is what i mean. I have 1 template(component) called `menu`. I want to use just that one component, for every menu. For example the head menu has 2 links. Let's say the links are food and drinks. If i click on drinks for example. I want the app to open the exact same component. But with 2 different links on the same spots in the html, for example soda's and iced drinks. And so on for every menu.

Comment: Or maybe this: ```js { path: '/food', component: Menu, props: {url_1: '/cold_food', url_1_name: 'Cold Food', url_2: '/warm_food', url_2_name: 'Warm food' } }
{ path: '/drinks', component: Menu, props: {url_1: '/cold_drinks', url_1_name: 'Cold Drinks', url_2: '/warm_drinks', url_2_name: 'Warm drinks' } }``` using the same variable props with different data

Comment: I still don't get it why to use params. The links should change depending on which route you are. But i don't need to send dynamic content through the urls like id's in your example.